# How to setup Soap API in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, soap

I'am new to this Soap Api and trying to implement soap api in laravel 4.2.

Added this in composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.2.*"
    },
```

added below one in **config/app.php**

```
'SoapWrapper' => 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper',
```

but am not getting how to use.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read documentation for using SoapWrapper?

Comment: Did you try to get the example up and running? https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

Answer (score 0):

**Steps For setup soap api in laravel**

1. Add artisaninweb/laravel-soap as requirement to composer.json

   {
       "require": {
           "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.2.*"
       }
   }
2. Add the service provider in app/config/app.php.

   'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider'
3. To use the facade add this to the facades in app/config/app.php.

   'SoapWrapper' => 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper'

[Laravel SoapClient Wrapper Document](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)